# Unable to use "chr" in python

Tags: python

I have had errors previously in my code that I have sorted now, but now that I run my code a new error appears

> string = (chr(addition))
>   TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

I do not know why this is appearing, and would appreciate it if anyone had a solution or an idea of how to fix this code.

The line that it has a problem with is `string = (chr(addition))`

The full code is posted below.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
choice = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? [e/d]: ")
string = ''
key1 = ''
message1 = ''
if choice == "e":
    message = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
    keyword = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")
    for A in message:
        if message in alphabet:
            message1 = (ord(message)) - 96
        for A in keyword:
            if keyword in alphabet:
                key1 = (ord(keyword)) - 96
    addition = key1 + message1
    string = (chr(addition))
    print (string)
```

Comment: Exactly what the error says: `chr` expects an integer, but you gave it a string. What are you trying to do on that line?

Comment: I am trying to return the number created by the "addition" line before into the corresponding letters - eg. "1" is "a" and "2" is "b" etc...

Comment: shouldn't `(ord(message))`  be `ord(A)`?

Comment: What are you trying to do, Vigenere cipher? Your logic is a bit flawed, on top of the error you reported you get. More specifically, the `for A in keyword:` block. Other than requiring `ord(A)` there, you iterate through the whole keyword and always end up with the equivalent of `key1 = ord(keyword[-1]) - 96`. Aren't you supposed to just fetch a letter cyclically?

Answer (score 2):

You initialize `key1` and `message1` to a string.

```
key1 = ''
message1 = ''
```

If these values are not overwritten, `addition = key1 + message1` will be a string too, so `chr(addition)` gets a string as parameter, as the error message states. You can easily find these bugs by [*debugging*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html)

A hot fix could be initializing them to zero, for example:

```
key1 = 0
message1 = 0
```

Comment: How would I overwrite the values?

Comment: @BigTommyVernon: You're already doing it conditionally in the loops above the assignment to `addition`. "Overwrite" just means "assign a new value". Clearly your loops aren't hitting the tests you expect to hit, so `key1` and `message` never get set to new values (confusingly, you loop setting `A` in both the inner and outer loop, which would be bad due to namestomping, but you never use `A`, so it doesn't cause problems; of course, not using `A` probably indicates a logic error).

Answer (score 0):

Would this be more like what you are looking for?
Each time it encrypts a letter it cycles through one letter of the the keyword. Once it has exhausted all keyword letters it goes back to the beginning (last if statement). 
I did not add any values in the message1 nor to key1 values because you should be the one to decide what fits your encrypting criteria. Since Python 3 encodes to Unicode instead of ASCII you can pass the chr() function values above 255. However it is good to notice that you cannot go bellow 0, as it would have happened in your previous code when you were subtracting 96 twice (from the keyword letter and from the message letter). Going bellow 0 will make the interpreter spit out a ValueError which states exactally that.

```
alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"
choice = input("Would you like to encrypt or decrypt? [e/d]: ")

if choice == "e":

        message = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
        keyword = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")    
        ik = len(keyword)
        i = 0
        string = ''

        for A in message:

            message1 = (ord(A))
            key1 = (ord(keyword[i]))

            addition = message1 + key1            
            string += (chr(addition))

            if i >= ik:
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1

        print (string)
```

If you would like to decrypt your message all you have to do then is subtract the key value:

```
elif choice == "d":

        message = input("Please insert the message you would like to use: ")
        keyword = input("Please insert the keyword you would like to use: ")

        ik = len(keyword)
        i = 0
        string = ''

        for A in message:

            message1 = (ord(A))
            key1 = (ord(keyword[i]))

            addition = message1 - key1          
            string += (chr(addition))

            if i >= ik:
                i = 0
            else:
                i += 1

        print (string)
```

Comment: I have tried your code and it is working how I intend it to be (I have encrypted on paper and the combination of letters is correct). However,  instead of printing letters from the alphabet, it is printing symbols.    ("ÞÞÒ")   . Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this problem? It would be greatly appreciated.